# Performing frwite more efficiently on Linux

Tags: linux

I'm using fwrite() while programming on Linux. It takes about a second to be performed. How can I achieve better, more efficient responses, preferably in the order of 20 miliseconds or less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `fwrite(3)` at all. Use `mmap(2)` to map the file into memory, and then perform pointer operations to access and write data within the map.

Answer (score 0):

try adding **O_DIRECT** to the option list on your (f)open statement.
You may have to use "ret = posix_memalign(&buffer, 512, PAGE_SIZE);" to align the buffer correctly.